# Bulk data processing using dapper and data warehouse

Tags: azure, dapper, sql-data-warehouse

I am using dapper in front end to process the data and inserting it into data warehouse. I have a scenario where i need to send bulk data from from dapper to data warehouse and perform few operation on it. I can do that using data table. i can create a data table, fill it with data and then pass that datatable to stored procedure which would do some processing on it.

But in data warehouse, i cannot create data table. But i need to send data in bulk  to stored procedure and process on it. how can i do that?

Process the data means i may have to perform multiple operation on data like updation, insertion or deletion on one or more tables using that data in stored procedure

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> But i need to send data in bulk to stored procedure and process on it. how can i do that?

You probably need a "table valued parameter", then, which is typically described via `DataTable`. Dapper can load data *into* a data-table via the `ExecuteReader` method (you can then use this reader to load the `DataTable`), or can pass a data-table *as a parameter* simply by: adding it as a parameter value in the usual way.

Comment: I already mentioned that data warehouse does not provide support for  DataTable. This solution won't work.